# Regex Non-Capturing Groups ins Scala

Tags: regex, scala, pattern-matching, capture

I want to use Regex non-capturing groups in scala, briefly worded "?:".

After hours of testing various cases I came here to search for a solution.
I found this question and its answer, but it didn't worked for me. 
[Is it possible to make non-capturing groups work in scala regexes when pattern matching](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18220899/is-it-possible-to-make-non-capturing-groups-work-in-scala-regexes-when-pattern-m)

So I wrote a minimal example to test the statement of the thread above.

```
val test = ("""(?:<.*>)(.*)(?:<.*>)""".r findFirstIn ("<test>hello</test>")) getOrElse ""
println("DEBUG MESSAGE (test): " + test)
```

Expected Output: `hello`

Real Output: `<test>hello</test>`

So what is wrong with my code?

Comment: Non-capture groups still get captured in the overall regex match (group 0), you are wanting the only other group (group 1) in this case. The other way (for the entire match to be what you want) you'd have to use lookarounds.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try with this regex instead:

```
<.*?>(.*?)<.*?>
```

**[Working demo](http://regex101.com/r/yK7aU2/1)**

[image]

**Scala code**

Also, try this code to get the content of capturing groups #1 like this:

```
val string = "<test>hello</test>"
val pattern = """<.*?>(.*?)<.*?>""".r
pattern.findAllIn(string).matchData foreach {
   m => println(m.group(1))
}
```

Comment: the problem was the way how I retrieved the result.

     pattern.findAllIn(descr).matchData.next.toString is working for me :)