# Regular Expression matching filename in Scala

Tags: regex, scala

I'm creating files and would like to create a new filename if it already exists, much like the way OS X/windows does with the (1) appended.

I'm learning Scala at the moment and even though I'm sure there's a already a method out there; I'd very much like to know how to do this without it.

My aim is to see if the file exists via a `private def doesFileExist(completeFilename: String) : Boolean = {
      logger.info("Checking if file already exists")
      Files.exists(Paths.get(completeFilename))
    }`

and then if it does I want to append the file name.  Because I need to check if the filename has already been updated I thought it'd be easiest to regex and see if there was something like `"/^[a-zA-Z0-9_-][\\d{1,2}][a-z0-9_\\.]{3,4}$/"`
Which I think will be suitable, I may be wrong, I haven't been able to test it. :)

I simply can't get it to compile no matter how many articles I read and so I'm not really sure how to fix it:

```
val RegexPattern = "/^[a-zA-Z0-9_-][\\d{1,2}][a-z0-9_\\.]{3,4}$/".r

  if (fileName.matches(RegexPattern)) {

  }
```

this clearly fails as it's expecting a string but I'm giving it Regex.  I then tried a match...

```
  fileName match {
    case RegexPattern => println("Etf")
  }
```

but that's also incorrect.  any help is appreciated, thank you.

Edit: A slightly different approach after finding an example online.

```
val pattern = "([0-9]+) ([A-Za-z]+)".r
  val pattern(count, fruit) = "100 Bananas"
  println(pattern)
  println(count)
  println(fruit)



  val RegexPattern = "(.+(?=\\/))(\\/)(.+(?=\\.))".r
  val RegexPattern(dir, delimeter, file) = "direct/ory/filename.ext"

  println(dir + " - " )
```

note, the bona example works fine, however mine does not.  The regex is valid as tested.

Comment: See my answer here where you must have parens in the `match`. http://stackoverflow.com/a/18223356/1296806  Otherwise you're just testing equality with your `Regex` object.

Comment: @som-snytt Thanks, i'll have another look now, would that also be applicable to my updated approach?

Comment: Do you mean your edit doesn't work?

Comment: @som-snytt - I've tried your example and it works perfectly with the abc, I've then tried to apply that to mine but still nothing.  Ideally, I'd like to be able to extract the filename based on the regex and then modify it. The regex I pasted works to pick out "direct/ory/filename.ext" as an example separating both 'direct/ory','/','filename' as groups

Comment: I get a MatchError on your RegexPattern example. First I would use triple quotes to avoid multi backslash, then correct the regex.

Comment: @som-snytt - thank you so much for your help. got there in the end :) I've added an answer but please feel free to correct it if I've made some foolish assumptions

Answer (score 0):

Just in case this can help someone else:

I didn't realise that the regex needs to match the exact string I was comparing against.

my old pattern of `val RegexPattern = "(.+(?=\\/))(\\/)(.+(?=\\.))".r` was ignoring the extension on the end.  I thought that, seeing as I didn't care about it, I wouldn't need to include it in the pattern.  Foolishly expecting it to match the first and omit the rest.

This became clear when playing with a much simpler example using:

```
val x = "(\\w)(\\w)".r
  val x(c, s) = "an"
  println(c, s)
```

if you remove the 's' it complains, similary if you ass a char without updating the regex, it complains.  Makes perfect sense in hindsight...

my working pattern with test is:

```
 val RegexPattern = "(.+(?=\\/))(\\/)(.+(?=\\.))(.*)".r
  val RegexPattern(dir, delimeter, file, ext) = "direct/ory/filename.ext"
  println(dir + " - "+ delimeter + " - " + file + " - " + ext)
```

Hope this helps someone else.

Comment: So as you found out, the pattern is "anchored" by default. You can use `"foo".r.unanchored` so the `match` expression works without your extra `.*`. I was too lazy to figure that out for you.

Comment: ! :D Excellent, thank you! I'm still only halfway there, now need to find out if file has (2) after it so that I can update it, trying to match this time :)